# Is there a way to trasnmit and receive data between simulated and real modem in UnetStack

Tags: unetstack

I am working on an *attribute based routing protocol*, where source node (Node A) collect attributes from two neighbor nodes (Node B and C) and based on ranking, Node A decides,to forward its data either to Node B or Node C

Now, I want to test this algorithm in test-bed with real UnetStack compatible modems,but there are only two real modems available,so if I create my topology with source node (Node A) running on laptop (using simulated modem) and neighbors(Node B and C) run using real modems. Is there a way that Node A can transmit and receive data from Node B and C. As Node B and C uses real modems.

Please let me know, how I can do this using only two real modems,also suggest if there is any other approach.

Comment: Interesting question. The short answer is yes, you can mix modems in the real world, and in the simulator in a Unet. But a modem in the real world can't send an acoustic transmission to the modem in the simulated world, or vise-versa, directly. Instead, you have to treat the simulated world as one subnet, and the real world as a different subnet, and connect the two networks through gateway nodes. In your case, nodes B and/or C will have instances in both the networks (simulated and real). If this type of solution is of interest to you, I can post an answer describing how to set it up.

Comment: Yes sir, kindly post your answer. Meanwhile, here I didn't understood, why nodes B and C will have instances in both simulated and real networks. Hope I will be getting answer for this too.

Answer (score 1):

When 2 modems are in water, they can communicate to each other using their PHYSICAL service agent (often named `phy`). Higher level agents such as `uwlink` then use `phy` to provide reliability, etc.

In a simulated environment, the PHYSICAL service is provided by the `HalfDuplexModem` agent (also named `phy`). This agent can talk to `HalfDuplexModem` agents on other simulated nodes, in the same way as modems underwater talk to each other. Higher level agents such as `uwlink` will use this `phy` for communication, and the application won't notice the difference.

However, the `HalfDuplexModem` in the simulated environment can't directly transmit a packet to a real modem in water, or receive a packet from it. Nodes in the simulated environment can only talk to each other, and the nodes in water can only talk to each other. So you can think of the simulated world as one subnet, and the real world as another subnet, even though both can be part of one Unet. To connect the subnets together, you need a gateway node that relays packets between the subnets.

To make things more concrete, let's say nodes B and C are in *water subnet*, and node A is in the *simulation subnet*. For node A to be able to talk to nodes B and C, you need at least one of node B or C to also be in the simulation subnet. To avoid multi-hop routing, let's say we prefer to have nodes B and C have presence in both subnets. The way to do this is to create a simulation with nodes A, B and C. Then, on nodes B and C, add in a new `phy2` PHYSICAL agent that will be used by a new `uwlink2` LINK service agent. The `phy2` agent will be a proxy for the real modem, sending any `TxFrameReq` or `DatagramReq` to the modem via a `UnetSocket`, and passing on `RxFrameNtf` (and other notifications) from the modem. Then set up the `router` on nodes B and C to route packets to nodes B and C via `uwlink2` and to node A via `uwlink`.

The agent setup on nodes B and C will look something like this:

```
|--------------------- Simulator -------------------------------|    |--- Modem ----|
[DatagramReq] --> router -A--> uwlink  --> phy (HalfDuplexModem)
                     \----BC-> uwlink2 --> phy2 -->  UnetSocket  --> phy (on modem)
```

with the overall network configuration:

```
    A -sim--- B ---(UnetSocket)--- modem B --\
     \                                    acoustic
      \-sim-- C ---(UnetSocket)--- modem C --/
```

The only agent you'd need to write is the proxy `phy2`. Fairly straightforward to write, as you need to send all messages to it via the socket to the modem, and send all notifications from the socket back on the notification topic for the proxy agent.

Comment: Sir, I was unable to try implementing your solution immediately, with some other work. Now I am working on it, but I couldn't clearly make out about implementing proxy ```phy2``` agent,  using UnetSocket between simulated nodes and real modems. Do I need to implement two Unetsocket, one for sending and another for receiving or a single Unetsocket will be enough? **Kindly help me, a skeleton code for implementing proxy** ```phy2``` **agent will be much helpful.**.

Comment: My reply above explains the behavior of `phy2`. If you can explain what is it that you don't understand, perhaps I can expand on that.