# Setting up router agent to use custom PHY (phy2) to send data from simulated modem to real modem

Tags: unetstack

I am working on an *attribute based routing protocol*, where source node (Node A) collect attributes from two neighbor nodes (Node B and C) and based on ranking, Node A decides,to forward its data either to Node B or Node C

Now, to test this algorithm in testbed with only two real UnetStack modems, as per the answer (by Prof. Mandar Chitre) to my previous post [Is there a way to trasnmit and receive data between simulated and real modem in UnetStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747505/is-there-a-way-to-trasnmit-and-receive-data-between-simulated-and-real-modem-in) I have implemented a `phy2` PHYSICAL agent, using UnetSocket, as a proxy to send data to real modem.

However, now I am able to send data from Node B (gateway node) in simulation subnet to Node B in another subnet from `phy2`, but I want to send data using `router`. Please let me know, how I can setup `router` agent to use phy2.

Answer (score 0):

The acoustic channel is not shared between the simulated and real modem, since the simulated modem can't transmit real sound in water, and so a real modem can't "hear" the simulated modem.

However, you could consider sending your information over a different link (e.g. [UdpLink](https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_wired_and_over_the_air_links.html)) that can send messages between a simulated node and a real modem, as long as both are connected to the same subnet over IP.

In fact, if you wanted a even closer simulation to your network, you could add an agent to the modem that would listen to the `DatagramNtf` from `UdpLink` and send an equivalent `RxFrameNtf` to `topic(phy)`, simulating a frame that came over the acoustic channel.